# How much faster is EBS than S3?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I have been looking but haven't found the answer to this simple question:  **In general, how must faster is AWS EBS than S3?**

I'm looking for a general ballpark answer in terms of "X times faster", "Y orders of magnitude faster", or a range of "somewhere # to # times faster depending on the specific use case".  I'll even take answers that give different use cases as long as there's actual relative performance NUMBERS associated with them.

---

And PLEASE, I do NOT want this thread to devolve into an architectural discussion of various other solutions I might try (e.g., DynamoDB, ElastiCache, RDS, etc) or the limitations imposed by whatever compute solution I choose (e.g. EC2, Lambda, ECS, etc).  Nor do I find "why would you want to do that?" counter-questions helpful no matter how often they appear on StackOverflow.

I'm just looking for "How much faster is EBS than S3?" because I haven't the slightest clue about it right now and haven't found a resource that gives me the type of answer I'm looking for.

---

Yes, yes, I know the real answer HAS to be "it depends" because determining the answer is infinitely more nuanced than my question.

I know that generally EBS is faster and that how much faster will depend on all sorts of things, like drive type, PIOPs, network speed, etc. all related to a specific use case.  But surely there's a general rule of thumb to help choose between the two when evaluating a system's design cost/benefit tradeoffs.  (*"No there isn't, and stop calling me Shirley."*)

If you need to know why I'm asking, let's say I'm just curious what the general speed difference is in case I ever want to decide between them when standing up a cheap-as-heck web site with a dirt-simple data store that is either on EBS or S3.  (Again, I'm NOT looking for design options).

Thanks

Comment: There is actually a general rule of thumb to choose between them, but it is unrelated to speed. When you need a single disk volume attached to a single EC2 instance for file storage, you use an EBS volume. When you need shared object storage, optionally including integration with other AWS services like SQS and Lambda, and optionally including serving a static website or static files for a larger website, you use S3. Either service can be configured to be as fast as you need it to be. You need to understand the fundamental differences in the two services instead of just looking at speed.

Comment: Think of S3 as a Dropbox/Google Drive type of service. Think of EBS as the hard disks of your servers. Note that using S3 as a "dirt simple" datastore probably won't work. For example you can't store a database on S3 and actually use it without downloading the entire thing down to your EC2 instance first, because S3 only allows you to upload and download entire files, S3 doesn't allow random access of content within those files.

Comment: Right. People do use S3 for that sort of thing. You could combine it with something like Lambda + ElasticSearch to allow searching the file contents. Connecting to S3 from an EC2 instance is extremely fast because it's a local network connection. Outside of AWS you can enable Transfer Acceleration or place CloudFront in front of the S3 bucket to make it fast. That's a very valid use case for S3 since it allows multiple servers, and serverless functions to access the data.

Comment: UVA did a study of S3/EBS performance some time ago. Not sure how valid it is today, but you may be interested to read it (search for uva hydrological amazon storage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the edge case where you are storing a file as an immutable data file and need to choose between S3 object store and EBS-based file system, both are valid options if you stretch your definition of validity.

**To answer the question:** EBS is faster (20x?) than S3, but more expensive and bound to a single EC2 instance.  S3 is slower but cheaper & more widely accessible to multiple resources.  S3 can be made to be much faster with some additional components (See @Mark B's comments above for more details)

You (and I) will want to use S3.

**Additional Info**
For immutable data files, S3 makes more sense in all normal cases: it's fast enough, cheaper, durable, and its contents are more available to multiple parallel processes, making it better for HA solutions.

EBS could make sense if you are hyper sensitive to speed (and can't achieve the speeds with S3+other components) and not cost or high availability.  EBS (or it's LAN-like equivalent EFS) is the only choice (out of the 2 being explored) if your file is going to be frequently updated (e.g., random access files for an RDBMS) or used by an application that requires a file system be in place.

(Thanks @Mark B for your patience, and @Jarmod for the objective data)